# How to always show the "increment arrows" in a matInput of type number?

Tags: angular-material

A picture is worth a 1024 words:

[image]

How do I force those arrows to show all the time ? **By default, they only appear on hover**.

```
<input matInput type="number" placeholder="Value" [(ngModel)]="myValue">
```

I could not find anything, and I am not even sure how these buttons are called.

Comment: I think this has to do with the browser implementation of numeric inputs. I don't see this behaviour in Firefox but do in Chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has to do with the browser as this isn't shown when using Firefox. You can add this css to fix the issue in Chrome.

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    opacity: 1;
}
```